# How can I turn a predicate expression into a SQL Where clause

Tags: c#, upsert, ef-core-2.1

I use EF Core in my application.  However, I have one part of the app where I desperately need to use SQL `MERGE` statements.  [Based on a post that I saw](https://www.flexlabs.org/2018/02/adding-upsert-support-for-entity-framework-core), relating to a project called FlexLabs.Upsert, I want to create some sort of `Upsert` extension that will generate a `MERGE` statement.

However, unlike the FlexLabs.Upsert project where the `ON` clause is simply created as a list of property equalities, I need to be able to pass in a more complex predicate like so:

```cs
DbContext.Upsert<Person>(person)
  .On((original, compare) => {
     return (original.AgencyId == compare.AgencyId 
       && original.AgencyReferenceId == compare.AgencyReferenceId)
     ||
     (original.SSN == compare.SSN)
     ||
     (original.Firstname == compare.Firstname
       && original.Lastname == compare.Lastname
       && original.Birthdate == compare.Birthdate)
  })
  .UpdateColumns(...)
  .RunAsync();
```

If there are no better options, I know something within EntityFramework is able to take a predicate and create a SQL `WHERE` clause.  Is there a way to hook into that, generate the `WHERE` clause to a string and then replace the `WHERE` with an `ON`?

Can someone help me figure out how to generate that clause or else point me to the code where the EF team actually generates the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Could you not just make your method signature accept a `Func<Person, Person, bool>`?  What is the signature of the `On` method?